# php prevent sscanf() from assuming '-' as string

Tags: php

It can distinguishes between decimal and '-'

```
$str = "1995-25";
$pat = sscanf( $str , "%d-%d);
print_r($pat);
```

It can also distinguish first '-' and following string

```
$str = "-of";
$pattern = sscanf ( $str , "-%s" );
print_r ( $pattern );
```

but when it comes to signify '-' in middle of a string
it assumes '-' as string
and more surprisingly the first %s reads it to the last
even considering 4 as string

```
$str = '-of-america-4';
$pat = sscanf ($str , "-%s-%s-%d");
print_r($pat);
// outputs [0] => of-america-4
```

Comment: `-` is a string. Add some expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%s` is a greedy match, you could use `%[^-]`

```php
<?php
$str = '-of-america-4';
$pat = sscanf($str , '-%[^-]-%[^-]-%d');
print_r($pat);
```

```
Array
(
    [0] => of
    [1] => america
    [2] => 4
)
```

Comment: thanks It worked, but can u explain more about  %[^-]  ? I've never seen this in programming before

Comment: it's not documentd by PHP, if you are using a unix system(macOS, linux), you can read more detail by `man sscanf`

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf